# Is it possible to send email for specific time in Salesforce?

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to send an email at specific time 10 am?

If possible using time-dependent workflow. Can anyone share me

Comment: What kind of information needs to be in the email? Does it need to happen regularly or just once at a specific time in the future? We need a little bit more info.

Comment: what can we use for regular happening? and what can we do for specific time in the future? can you help me out with this both scenario?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it using **Time Dependent Workflow** [Take a look at this question](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DN2ZAAW)